# Program Option Button in Excel to run two different macros or actions

Tags: vba, excel, radio-button

Simple question that I can't seem to get right: I have set up a macro that hides a few cells and another one that shows those same cells. When I run them independently they work fine. But i'm trying to set an option button or a check box that will run both macros. For example: if the box is checked, it shows the cells, if it is unchecked, it hides them.

I have only been able to assign one macro on click, but this doesn't work because it doesn't take into consideration the state of the button. I've tried with an IF, like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    Columns("Q:R").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("A2").Select
Else
    Columns("Q:R").Select
    Range("R1").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range("A2").Select
End If

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to toggle, starting with an unticked check box and visible columns

```
Sub CheckBox2_Click()
  Columns("Q:R").Select
  Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = not (Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden)
  Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to worry about the state of the button. You really just need to reverse the state on click no matter what. You can just negate whatever the current state is.

```
Range("Q:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = Not Range("Q:R").EntireColumn.Hidden
Range("A2").Select
```

That being said, the logic you have is solid. What do you mean when you say it's not working? Does it never work, or only the first time you click the checkbox?